# Assigning 0 value to missing element: MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, missing-data

I have two set of matrices A and B as below:

```
A = [NaN    NaN    NaN  0.61    NaN 0.6
     NaN    2.14    NaN 0.57    NaN 0.83
     NaN    5.11    NaN 2.45    NaN 2.35
     NaN    10.93   NaN 5.58    6.13    5.95];
B = [0.76   2.24    1.89    0.61    -0.46   0.6
    1.30    2.14    2.93    0.57    0.65    0.83
    2.29    5.11    4.88    2.45    1.71    2.35
    6.65    10.93   9.39    5.58    6.13    5.95]
```

The matrix B contains imputed values from matrix A. I need to find out the element which was imputed corresponding to matrix A and if it is negative, put a value of 0 for that element. For example, the element at (2,5) has a value of -0.46, which was NaN in original matrix A. So for this element I need to assign 0 value in matrix B.

Comment: You mean element (1,5) right? What if it is a positive number? Eg. (1,1) is 0.76 in `B` so what does it become? Moreover it looks like you have not accepted ay answer to your previous questions (that that received an answer). Any reasons for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
B(isnan(A) & (B < 0)) = 0;
```